# How to copy text from less

Tags: linux, less, terminal-emulator

How might one copy the entire buffer being displayed by less?
No need to select specific text, I want it all.
Copying to the clipboard is preferable but if we can output it to a file that works too.

I've tried using generic `vim` commands like :w and the ones listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620018/vi-editor-copy-all-the-lines-to-clipboard) but `less` doesn't seem to accept commands like that.

**EDIT**
I must be able to do this from *within* `less`. Let's say that `less` is `pipe`ed to from an alias, I have no control over how `less` is actually called. I am just presented with the result.
I found a way to save the buffer (see my answer below) so now I just need to see if there is any way to select and copy. There probably isn't, given the restrictions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dump `less` buffer into clipboard using `xsel` as follows:

1. Open file `$ less file.txt`
2. In `less` press `|`(pipe) then `$`
3. Write `xsel -i` and press *Enter*

`less` buffer content should be copied.

Comment: for other people, as @ahilsend [noted](https://superuser.com/questions/625744/how-to-copy-text-from-less/1504492#comment778910_625778) `xsel -i` is good for the middle-click buffer, but use `xsel -ib` if you wanted the paste buffer instead

Comment: For macOS users you can replace `xsel -i` with `pbcopy`

Answer (score 7):

Type the command `:s` from within `less` to write the buffer to a 'log' file.

[Source](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_less.htm):
`The "s" command is equivalent to specifying -o from within less`

Comment: Still seeking answer for `save to clipboard`

Comment: it seems [possible](https://superuser.com/a/865484/241800) to create a clipboard file device and then use `:s /dev/clipboard` (well, `~/.dev/clipboard`, maybe)

Answer (score 3):

1. install `xsel` first
2. copy to clipboard using xsel: `less filename.txt | xsel -i`
3. paste it:
   `xsel -o`

Comment: Maybe add the `-b` option to use the clipboard selection.

Comment: Thanks @ahilsend, you are right. By the way I use clipit to sync clipboards and it works well.

Comment: I should be more specific, I do not start the `less` command. The `less` view is up, and you must copy its contents then. So using some sort of inbuilt functionality I think is necessary. Piping can't be used

Answer (score 3):

You can repurpose less's 'v' command for this.

Look at the manpage for less, specifically about LESSEDIT.  You can use @rwxrwxrwx's suggestion, if you do a little set-up ahead of time (maybe in your .bashrc):

```
bash$ export LESSEDIT="%E < %f"
bash$ export EDITOR="xsel -ib"
```

When less runs, press 'v' to open the present file in the $EDITOR; in this case, open it with `xsel -ib < {the file's name}`.

Using `xsel -ib` puts the data on the clipboard, so you can ctrl-V to paste the data where you want it.

Comment: as far as I know, you cannot use `:v` when the input comes from `std-in`, which, in my case, it is. Will this method somehow mediate this?

Comment: You can pipe any buffer's contents to the clipboard with `g|$xsel -ib`.

Comment: You can also modify your PATH to replace `less` with something that redirects to vim.

Comment: That would work, actually. Very intrusive, but will work, @Neil

Comment: When I try it I get less /etc/php.ini | xsel -ib
xsel: Can't open display: (null)
 what am I doing wrong?