# Is there a way to create a /dev/clipboard like in Cygwin?

Tags: linux, filesystems, cygwin, copy-paste, clipboard

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/750466/113195) says, that Cygwin features a `/dev/clipboard` device, that's in sync with the default Windows clipboard.

Is there any way to have that same feature in Linux for the Primary clipboard? Perhaps someone wrote a FUSE driver or such?

More specifically, I'm looking for a file-like device on Linux, that allows the following:

```
$ echo Foo > /dev/clipboard
# clipboard content: "Foo", usable via Ctrl-V
# set clipboard via Ctrl-C to "Bar"
$ cat /dev/clipboard > test.txt
# test.txt content: "Bar"
```

Answer (score 4):

Having a FUSE daemon talk X11 would certainly be possible. But there are some other problems:

> Nitpick: "Primary clipboard" contradicts itself. X11 has *two* commonly used 'selections'; the one called "PRIMARY" is used when you select and middle-click, and the one called "CLIPBOARD" is used when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>.

Cygwin's `/dev/clipboard` is implemented in the cygwin1 runtime, so its code runs **in the same context as the accessing program itself**. If two users try to read it, they both see their own clipboard contents, because they're accessing it themselves, directly.

Linux filesystem mounts, meanwhile, are **global** – **all read requests go through a single FUSE server process** (for that FUSE mount); meaning, it doesn't know for sure which X server's clipboard it should read.

*(Remember that there can be multiple users logged in, and multiple X servers running at once.)*

There are three possible solutions for the multi-user problem:

- Have a single system-wide FUSE mount at `/dev/clipboard`. Every time the FUSE daemon receives a open request, it needs to obtain the requesting program's PID, access `/proc/<pid>/environ`, extract DISPLAY= & XAUTHORITY= from it, use that information to connect to the correct X server, and read the clipboard.
- Instead of /dev, put the special file in the user's home directory, e.g. `~/clipboard`. Each user runs a separate copy of the daemon. GNOME's Gvfs uses this method for `/run/user/*/gvfs` (earlier `~/.gvfs`). It limits each user to one graphical session, but that's fine – there are many other things that only work once per user, too.
- Set up a new *mount namespace* when logging in, e.g. using `pam_namespace`, so that each session would have a separate view of what's mounted where (inheriting from the root namespace, but being able to mount e.g. /dev/clipboard without it being visible from the outside). The FUSE daemon then is launched by the X session manager, same as in the previous method, but not limited to one session per user.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for the answer. I haven't thought of the multi-user problem, that Cygwin doesn't have.